# Large Numbers Requiring More than 64 bit Representation

Tags: java, biginteger

I am using java and have to deal with numbers larger than long (which is 64 bits). What should I use? What is the size of BigInteger in java?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question, you should use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

They can be as large as you need - until you run out of memory.

Comment: the problem is I have to find out the square root of a the number. But there is no  inbuilt library to find the square roo t of a bug integer.

Comment: @Ashwin: Wait a minute -- if the square root is not guaranteed to be decimal, why are you not simply using a double?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : Like I said, my number exceeds 64 bits, where as size of double is 64 bits

Comment: @Ashwin: if the number's square root is not a decimal number than this makes no sense. Create a double that gets close to the value of your number and the square root of this will likely be reasonably accurate -- unless you have a specific reason for extreme precision. If you do, it would be nice to know just what that reason is.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : okay tell me what is the size of double.

Comment: @Ashwin - Google it ... or look it up in Wikipedia, the Oracle Java tutorial, the JVM specs, etc, etc.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the size of BigInteger in java?

That's a little bit tricky.  The problem is that there is no clear specification of the limit in the javadocs.

- The class uses an `int[]` to represent the magnitude.  This means it could  potentially represent numbers up to `((2^32)^(2^31 - 1)`.
- The API has a method that returns the number as a 2's complement byte array.  The limit for this is `((2^8)^(2^31 - 1)`.
- The API has another method that returns the size of the number in bits ... as an `int`.  This implies a limit of `2^(2^31 - 1)` or maybe `2^(2^32)`.

In practice, these numbers are all so large that you will *probably* run into heap space limits (or CPU performance limits) first.

---

> the problem is I have to find out the square root of a the number.

You should be able to find an algorithm for calculating square roots in your undergraduate maths text books (or Wikipedia).  Coding it should be a simple task.

(I'd point you at example code, except that this smells like "homework", and I don't entirely trust the code that I found.)

Don't forget that *most* integers have an irrational square-root ...

Answer (score 2):

you are looking either for the class BigDecimal or if you just need integers, than BigInteger.  Its arbitrary precision, so the size changes based on how big the numbers are that you input

Answer (score 0):

To find a square root of a BigInteger you have to do a google search with "-StackOverflow" answers omitted. https://www.google.com/search?q=java+extract+root+bignum&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=java+root+BigInteger+-stackoverflow.com+-stackexchange.com yields the first link to http://faruk.akgul.org/blog/javas-missing-algorithm-biginteger-sqrt/ Here is one algorithm. Java is supposed to be "write once, use everywhere". Well, some SO users believe that you must reinvent the wheel. Ask them for a module they answer "smells like a homework, do it yourself". And yes, BigInteger is half baked. It can't do logarithms or roots out of the box. It is extremely slow. The algorithm is given below.

```
BigInteger sqrt(BigInteger n) {
  BigInteger a = BigInteger.ONE;
  BigInteger b = new BigInteger(n.shiftRight(5).add(new BigInteger("8")).toString());
  while(b.compareTo(a) >= 0) {
    BigInteger mid = new BigInteger(a.add(b).shiftRight(1).toString());
    if(mid.multiply(mid).compareTo(n) > 0) b = mid.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
    else a = mid.add(BigInteger.ONE);
  }
  return a.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Ha40 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = scan.nextInt();
    long d=scan.nextLong();
    String st=" ";
    st=scan.next();
    st+= scan.nextLine();
    // Write your code here.

    System.out.println("String: " + st);
    System.out.println("Double: " + d);
    System.out.println("Int: " + i);
}
```

}

input are:2147483647
235345345345.234534
  fsdfsdf   sdf but ans is not getting upto the mark